# Constrained optimisation problem with Maximize

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am trying to solve a constrained maximisation problem in Mathematica but I am getting the same output as my problem. My input is

```
Maximize[{Integrate[-E^(-c (1 - L)^α + d V) L V + 
E^(-a (1 - L)^α - b V) (-1 + L V) - Exp[-x]*f[y], {y, w*L - o, w*L + o} , 
Assumptions -> {w*L - o, w*L + o} > 0 && o > 0], 0 <= L <= 1, 
 0 <= V <= 1}, 
{L, V}]
```

I hope someone can help. Have tried numerical options but I get an error message saying the function is not a number when I do.

Comment: If you use Integrate, you don't need to use `\[DifferentialD]y`. And, you don't tell us what `f` is.

Comment: @Carl I removed `\[DifferentialD]y` already in the hope that nobody has seen it.

Comment: I am integrating over y which is distributed according to some probability density function f[y] but I am differentiating with respect to L and V. This is important since L enters in the limits of integration but is NOT the variable I'm integrating over.

Comment: Have you tried this with setting values for $\alpha$, `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `o`, `x`, and `w` and a particular function `f[y]` ?

Comment: A simple task. We can put `f[y]=f=const` and integrate. After that, apply the optimization and see what does not work. `Maximize` does not work because of the large number of undefined parameters.

Comment: The integral can be performed without difficulty, yielding `2 o (-E^(-c (1 - L)^α + d V) L V + E^(-a (1 - L)^α - b V) (-1 + L V)) - E^-x (-g[-o + L w] + g[o + L w])`, where `g` is the antiderivative of `f`.  Not surprisingly, `Maximize` cannot handle this expression either.  Also, setting the derivatives with respect to `L` and  `V` to zero leaves a pair of equations which `Solve` cannot handle.